# AngularJS Select box not updating when model is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a controller like this

```
  app.controller("ReservationCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.rooms = [{id: 1, name: "Room 1"}, {id: 2, name: "Room 2", }];
    $scope.reservation = {id: 1, time: "9AM", room: {id: 2, name: "Room 2"}};

});
```

A view that looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="reservation.room" ng-options="room as room.name for room in rooms"></select>
```

The problem is that the select box won't bind to the correct room unless I say

```
$scope.reservation.room = $scope.rooms[1];
```

This is rather inconvenient for development as the room is not the only field on the `reservation` model that needs to be bound to a select box. How can I apply the binding without doing this extra step?

Also, the binding breaks again if I do something like

```
$http.get("/reservation/2").success(function(data) { $scope.reservation = angular.copy(data); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the key to this problem is the `track by` clause in the `ng-options` directive. See my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kshep92/gw6yt2tp/1/) 
As you will see, the whole model is being updated and not just its ID. The documentation says that `select as` and `track by` were not meant to be used together, but the example they used to illustrate this is a bit different from mine.

Since I've received no feedback from the official Angular channels on this matter to date, I'm gonna mark this as solved and move on.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because,

in your `ng-options` if you select an option, the selected value is an object

**EX**: if you select first option then model value is an object which is the first element in the `$scope.rooms` (`{id: 1, name: "Room 1"}`).

objects are reference type data type. So what it does is if the objects create one time then all of its usage are pointing to that object. have a look at this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx).

So your selected value is an object which is a reference type. In your case you have two independent objects for the `$scope.reservation.room` and the `{id: 2, name: "Room 2"}` which is in `rooms` array. note that they are in separated memory slots.

In your working case both of the `$scope.reservation.room` and the `{id: 2, name: "Room 2"}` which is in `rooms` array are pointing to same memory slot because you have equals the two as `$scope.reservation.room = $scope.rooms[1];` This means `$scope.reservation.room` & `$scope.rooms[1]` both are pointing to the same object in the memory.

---

To work this out you can do something different than your working solution.

change the `ng-repeat` as following

```
...ng-options="room.id as room.name for room in rooms"...
```

and change the `ng-model`

```
....ng-model="reservation.id"....
```

this will select the `id` of the option as the selected value for **EX** if you select the first option then the model value will be `1` which is the `id` of the first option.

in this case selected model values are primitive(`like 1,2,3..`) type data then its not going to search for the objects in memory instead it will get the value of stack and check with the option values and select the correct one.

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pghTSOTmQv6d4VzDLJyi?p=preview) this will select the second option initially.

------------------------------------------------- **SUMMARY** -------------------------------------------------

If the selected model value is an `object` then it will check the memory address of the selected object and the all objects of the `$scope.rooms` and check if there is a matching element and select the matching option if one is found. if no one found then nothing will select.

If the model values are primitive like `1,2,3..` it will search the value and check if there any matching `option` `value` if one is found it will select that option.

Answer (score 1):

When the view is loaded, the select box has no selected value because the room object in `$scope.reservation` is not the same object as the one in `$scope.rooms`, event if it has the same values.

Thats why your example does not work (**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x32b1jf5/)**)

But this one works:

```
$scope.rooms = [{id: 1, name: "Room 1"}, {id: 2, name: "Room 2"}];
$scope.reservation = {
    id: 1,
    time: "9AM",
    room: $scope.rooms[1]  // <-- now the reservation room references a valid ng-repeated room
};
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x32b1jf5/2/)**

---

To avoid problems, I'll suggest you bind to the variable of your select box only the room id of the reservation. Because it is a primitive type, the comparison will be made by value, and that will solve also your second use case. Moreover, you better not duplicate data in the reservation object. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x32b1jf5/3/)

If you need to display the name of the reserved (selected) room, you could easily write a `getRoomById` function that will look into the array of rooms.

Comment: That's fine, but how do I get the automatic binding for my second use case where I assign the value of the `reservation` object via the return of an $http call?

Comment: With your configuration of the `<select>` element, you have to make sure that `$scope.reservation.room` references an object from the array `$scope.room` so as to have the binding. To avoid problems, I'll suggest you bind only the room id in the ng-model. Because it is a primitive type, the comparison can happen by value. After all, in your reservation object you better not duplicate data, you need only the id of the room. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x32b1jf5/3/)

Comment: There's a possibility that this could be the solution, but if you look at [my changes](http://jsfiddle.net/x32b1jf5/4/) you will see that using the select box only switches one attribute of the model (id) and not the entire model itself. You approach does fix the problem of broken bindings when I change the entire `reservation` model though. Give me a little more time to investigate this further or get some more answers before I accept this one.

Comment: So it seems the key to this problem is the `track by` clause in the `ng-options` directive. See my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kshep92/gw6yt2tp/1/) 
As you will see, the whole model is being updated and not just its ID. The documentation says that `select as` and `track by` shouldn't be used in the same expression as they are incompatible, but it looks like they work fine to me...

Answer (score -1):

Change the scope only when the value changes.

```
if($scope.reservation.room != $scope.rooms[1])
   $scope.reservation.room = $scope.rooms[1];
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.